# Remote desktop powershell indication

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, windows-server

I'm trying to automate the remote desktop process (from windows client to windows server) for a service I'm working on.
To do so, I'm using the following Powershell script:

```
$ProcessInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$Process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process

$ProcessInfo.FileName = "$($env:SystemRoot)\system32\cmdkey.exe"
$ProcessInfo.Arguments = "/generic:TERMSRV/$ComputerCmdkey /user:$User /pass:$Password"
$ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle]::Hidden
$Process.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo
if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($ComputerCmdkey,'Adding credentials to store')) {
       [void]$Process.Start()
}

$ProcessInfo.FileName = "$($env:SystemRoot)\system32\mstsc.exe"
$ProcessInfo.Arguments = "$MstscArguments /v $Computer"
$ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle]::Normal
$Process.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo
if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Computer,'Connecting mstsc')) {
    [void]$Process.Start()
}
```

This script works perfectly fine. What i'm missing is an indication on the **client side** (other than the UI window - some return value or event log) that can tell me whether the connection was successful or did it fail.
Can anyone here help with it?
Thanks

Comment: Remote Desktop sessions are for interactive user access. The user will see whether or not he got a remote desktop. What are you trying to accomplish by automating this that can't be done with an RDP connection manager like [RDCMan](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989)?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, Thanks for the quick reply.
What I want is he ability to iterate several users on a single machine of several machines for a single user.

Comment: To do *what* exactly?

Comment: I need to simulate a situation that a single user connects to several machines. On each machine the user will open a specific website and log on (same user account - different IP addresses).
I need it for testing my website

Comment: Using `Invok-Command` or `Start-Job` to run `Invoke-WebRequest`or `New-Object -COM 'InternetExplorer.Application'` on remote hosts might be a better approach for that.